# Combinatorics: How many ways are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Having trouble with this problem.
A group of balls is numbered 1-9. How many ways are there to select 5 balls if you do not want to get balls 1 AND 2, nor do you want 1 AND 3? For example you could have balls 1 and 3 or 3 and 2 in the set and it would be fine. Order is irrelevant.

Comment: Your description of the problem does not make sense.  You say pretty clearly that the five balls cannot include both "1 AND 3", then immediately turn around and say "For example you could have balls 1 and 3... and it would be fine."

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to calculate the complement.

The number of ways you can pick $5$ balls with $1$ and $2$ but **not** $3$ included is ${6 \choose 3}$. Similarly the number of ways of having $1$ and $3$ but **not** $2$ is also ${6 \choose 3}$. The way of picking $5$ balls such that you have $1$, $2$ **and** $3$ is ${6 \choose 2}$.

Therefore your answer is

$${9 \choose 5} - \left(2\cdot {6 \choose 3} + {6 \choose 2}\right) = 71.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let A be the selections including 1 and 2, B be the selections including 1 and 3, and let S be all selections.

Then $\big|\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\big|=\big|S\big|-\big|A\big|-\big|B\big|+\big|A\cap B\big|=\dbinom{9}{5}-2\dbinom{7}{3}+\dbinom{6}{2}=71$